# What is the difference between 2nd and mixed conditional?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Could someone explain the difference in meaning between these two forms of conditional?

> 1.If I had time, I would be there.
>   2.I would have been there if I had time.

Comment: No such thing.  This is a myth: **English does *not* have numbered conditionals**. [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from “If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”, Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, ELT Journal 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press, doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Comment: If everyone had learned conditionals the same way, this question would be mute. Alas, [Start here:](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/mixed-conditional/) Then research *conditional sentences*.

Comment: "If I wasn't afraid of spiders, I would have picked it up."  
Would it be correct to say:
If I was afraid of spiders, I wouldn't have picked it up?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/316123/2085).

Answer (score 1):

The first refers to the present moment, the second to a time in the past.

(in the second case "I would have been there if I had had time" would seem more common, however, referring to a specific instance; the use of the simple past in (2) implies that your not having time was a more or less continuous state rather than being specific to one event or instance)

Comment: '"I would have been there if I had had time" would seem more common': Indeed.

Comment: Thank you. But what about this if I would like to refer to the past:

If I knew her number I would call her. May I say: I would have called or is it the only way to use this with "If I had known"? 

I am rather confused when taking this in compare with negative analogue : If I didn't love her, I wouldn't have married her.

Comment: @gerol2000 try to see the threads here: http://goo.gl/36aMVh